# Programatically creating an iterator from mapping functions in Rust

Tags: function, rust, dynamic, iterator, flatmap

I'm trying to write code like the following, but where I apply `f1` and `f2` some variable number of times:

```rust
#![feature(impl_trait_in_bindings)]

fn f1(c: char) -> impl IntoIterator<Item = char> {
    vec!['A', c]
}

fn f2(c: char) -> impl IntoIterator<Item = char> {
    vec!['C', 'D', c] 
}

fn main() {
    let x = vec!['X', 'X', 'X'];

    let v: impl Iterator<Item = char> = x.into_iter();
    let v = v.flat_map(f1);
    let v = v.flat_map(f2);

    println!("Force evaluation of five elements: {:?}", v.take(5).collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

I'd like to replace the `let v = ...` lines with a loop that iteratively reassigns v, like

```rust
    let mut v: impl Iterator<Item = char> = x.into_iter();
    for i in 0..f1Times {
      v = v.flat_map(f1);
    }
    for i in 0..f2Times {
      v = v.flat_map(f2);
    }
```

... e.g. for my use case I may have several functions and I won't know which ones (or how many times) to apply ahead of time. I'd like the result to be an iterator that I can `take` only a limited number of items from, and I'd like to avoid invoking any functions that aren't needed to generate those items.

I can't get the types to work. For instance with the `let mut` block I proposed above I get:

```
mismatched types
expected opaque type `impl Iterator`
        found struct `FlatMap<impl Iterator, impl IntoIterator, fn(char) -> impl IntoIterator {f1}>`
```

Is there a good way to build up this sort of iterator programatically?

Comment: Just to clarify: calling `flat_map(f1)` `n` times with `3` initial values and flattens to `2` values each will balloon to `3*2^n` elements. [This](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=22f880061ddfd921e22afab776835f36) is what you expect? (with being able to control `n` dynamically and chain the same with `f2` of course)

Comment: Yes indeed! This particular code is a contrived example to show my question about types; the actual functions I want to call will not expand the size of the output exponentially :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've found this pattern works, but still don't know if it's idiomatic or recommended...

```rust
#![feature(impl_trait_in_bindings)]

fn f1(c: char) -> impl Iterator<Item = char> {
    Box::new(vec!['A', c].into_iter())
}

fn f2(c: char) -> impl Iterator<Item = char> {
    Box::new(vec!['C', 'D', c].into_iter())
}

fn main() {
    let x = vec!['X', 'X', 'X'];

    let mut v: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = char>> = Box::new(x.into_iter());
    let f1_ntimes = 2;
    for _i in 0..f1NTimes {
        v = Box::new(v.into_iter().flat_map(f1));
    }

    let f2_ntimes = 2;
    for _i in 0..f2_ntimes {
        v = Box::new(v.into_iter().flat_map(f2));
    }

    println!("Force evaluation of five elements: {:?}", v.take(5).collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

Comment: It will be slow, but this is a possibility.

Comment: I don't think there's another way to do it just using methods in the standard library or itertools crate. You'd probably have to roll your own iterator to avoid all the boxes.